# Erro de Conexão ao Banco de Dados Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, ado

Estou desenvolvendo um WebService em Visual Studio 2019 Community acessando o banco de dados no SQL Server através do ADO. Estou usando o "SQL Server Management Studio v18.6".

Quando vou abrir o banco de dados aparece o seguinte erro:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>
> HResult=0x80131904
>
> Message=Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de Local Database Runtime. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.
> )  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> StackTrace:
>
> <Não é possível avaliar o rastreamento da pilha de exceção>

O meu código é:

```
  readonly string conexaoString = @"server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;database=ControlDB;uid=sa;password=xxxxx;";

  using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(conexaoString))
  {
        string Sql = "Select Top 1 Id From Pessoa Order By Id Desc";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Sql, conexao);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conexao.Open();

        SqlDataReader lido = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

O erro acontece na execução da linha `conexao.Open();`.

Se faço a abertura do banco de dados numa aplicação Web (.net core) o banco de dados é aberto normalmente.

Como posso resolver esse problema?